# Regex : how to replace this string in java?

Tags: java, regex

So I have this **java String**.

```
<script type="text/javascript"  
    src="https://c328740.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
<script type='text/x-mathjax-config'>
    MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});
</script>
```

that I want to replace with `""`.

What I am doing is this :

```
.replaceAll("(<img[^>]*>)|(<script[^>]*>)", "")
```

but this doesn't remove  `MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});` between the script tags.

the above regex looks for all `<img>` tags also and replaces them with `""`, the same I want to achive for the above shown `<script>` tags and everything **between** them also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be working

```
str = Pattern.compile("<img .+?</img>|<script .+?</script>", Pattern.DOTALL).matcher(str).replaceAll("");
```

note that your str has CRLF this why DOTALL

Comment: what is s here the java string.

Comment: It worked for me thanks could I add more regexs' with `|` symbol lets say if I want to replace <br> also then `"<img .+?</img>|<script .+?</script>|<br>"` should work ?

Answer (score 0):

```
If you want to replace part of the string between the tags to replace then try this.

string = string.replaceAll("(<script>.*?)Here is our keyword which should be replaced(.*?</script>)","$1Replaced with:$2");
```

If you want to replace everything between the tags with "" then try this.

```
s = s.replaceAll("(<script>).*?(</script>)","");
```